# public synonym creation

Tags: oracle, public, synonym

How can I create a public synonym in oracle 7.3.4 for a common table located in different users.

Comment: Oracle 7.3.4? Wow, I think the last one I saw of those was 1999.

Answer (score 2):

"common table located in different users" doesn't make sense .. if each user has his/her own table in their own schema, then you have multiple tables, and a public synonym won't work.

With a public synonym you have a single table (located in a "central" schema) that everyone can use (if the appropriate rights are GRANTed, as APC has noted).

All the synonym does is that it makes addressing the table a little bit easier, instead of `some_user.some_table` you can use `some_table`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a user with CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM privilege.

This is not granted to non SYSDBA accounts by default, and should be granted only with due consideration.  There is a matching DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM privilege.

Remember that a synonym is just a name (an interface).  It doesn't grant privileges on the underlying object.